# Same file can not be uploaded twice in angularjs using fileModel

Tags: angularjs, file-upload

I am using angular js fileModel directive to upload file, which is as below

```
angular.module('MyProject').directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;
            element.bind('change', function(){
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

And I am using the same in html as below,

```
 <input type='file' class="imgInp" file-model="tenantLogoFile"/>
```

If I select one file then Its fine for me to capture the file chosen by user by using `$watch` on "tenantLogoFile". But if I am supposed to upload same file (Without refreshing page) immediately again, `$watch` does not get fired and ultimately I am unable upload the file.

I tried setting `$scope.tenantLogoFile = null` after first time successful upload, but no use, Can anyone help me please?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZG9re/7081/ try this

Comment: Hi Aayushi I studied you code, But I did not understand, where is the call to "$scope.uploadFile" function?

Comment: Sorry forgot to update that, check this one: http://jsfiddle.net/ZG9re/7161/

Comment: Hi, This not working Aayushi.. Is this chrome problem??? I am fed up with this. Can you upload SAME FILE back to back without refreshing page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anyways guys I found a workaround as below,

```
<input type='file' file-model="myFile" ng-click="clearFileSelection();"/>
```

I wrote a function named "clearFileSelection" in controller and called it on every subsequent click on the file chooser button, so that the previous file contents got cleared, function code is as below.

```
$scope.clearFileSelection = function(){
        angular.element("input[type='file']").val(null);
    }
```

I hope this will definitely help some other strugglers like me.. Happyyy Coding..!!

Answer (score 0):

**You don't have to alter your HTML or controller. As your directive is restrict to attribute. Its better use element.on('click',fn) for this scenario.**

```
angular.module('MyProject').directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;
            *element.on('click', function(){
                angular.element("input[type='file']").val(null);
            });*
            element.bind('change', function(){
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Hi Krishan. I suggest you put your code into a markdown code fence. Meaning enclose it in 3 backticks like ``` lines of code go in here  ``` . That will make your answer much easier to read.